# Implementing Search criteria using MVC return no record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement search criteria which bind to Kendo Ui grid. However it return no record and no error display. In SearchProduct it return the data but it would not bind to grid

Is there something i missed?

**Controller code :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchProduct(ProductSearchCriteria criteria)
{          
    string nameCriteria = string.Empty;
    string descCriteria = string.Empty;

    TTSEntities dc = new TTSEntities();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(criteria.Name))
      nameCriteria = criteria.Name.ToLower().Trim();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(criteria.Community))
      descCriteria = criteria.Desc.ToLower().Trim();

    var results = dc.Products.AsQueryable();
    if (criteria.Name!= null)
        results = results.Where(b => b.Name== criteria.Name);

    if (criteria.Desc!= null)
        results = results.Where(b => b.Desc== criteria.Desc);

    return PartialView("_ProductGrid", results.ToList());
}
```

**Index.cshtml :**

```
@model HHIMS_Web_App.Models.ProductSearchCriteria

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="headerpanel">
      <fieldset>
        <legend style="font-size:14px">Search Criteria</legend>
        <div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Desc)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Desc)
            </div>
            <div class="smallBox">
                <input type="button" value="Search" id="btnProductSearch" style="height:33px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnProductSearch').click(function (e) {
            var searchParameters = GetSearchParameters();
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(searchParameters, null, 2);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/ProductDetails/SearchProduct/")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: jsonData,
                datatype: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#btnProductSearch').replaceWith(data);
                },
                error: function (request, status, err) {
                    alert(status);
                    alert(err);
                }
            });

        });

        function GetSearchParameters() {
            var hrn = $("#Name").val();
            var community = $("#Desc").val();

            return { Name: name,
                Desc: desc
            };
        }
    });

</script>
```

**_ProductGrid View :**

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="searchResults">
        <legend style="font-size:14px">Search Result</legend>
        <br />
        <div>
          @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TTP.Models.ProductModel>()

                .Name("Product")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:10px; width:500px" })
                .Columns(columns =>
                {

                    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Desc);
                })
                .AutoBind(false)
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                .Sortable()
                    //.Pageable()
                .Pageable(paging => paging
                    .Input(false)
                    .Numeric(true)

                    .PreviousNext(true)
                    .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 25, 50 })
                    .Refresh(false)
                )
                .Selectable()
                .Scrollable()
                .ColumnMenu(c => c.Columns(false))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()//bind with Ajax instead server bind
                    .PageSize(10)
                    .ServerOperation(true)
                    .Model(model =>
                      {
                        model.Id(p => p.Name);
                      }
                    )
                )
            )

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SearchProduct` action should return `JSON` data for the grid.

See the [*Kendo Grid Demo*](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) - choose the `ASP.NET MVC` tab and look at the `IndexController.Products_Read` code.

You want something like this:

```
public ActionResult SearchProduct(
  ProductSearchCriteria criteria,
  [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsr
)
{
  IQueryable<Product> query = ...

  return Json( query.ToDataSourceResult( dsr ) );
}
```

---

To pass the search parameters as extra data with the read ajax request, use the [*Data*](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/CrudOperationBuilder) method:

```
dataSource.Read( read => read.Data( "GetSearchParameters" ) )
```

See [*Kendo: Ajax Binding - Pass Additional Data to Action Method*](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-action-method)